# Using local JS functions together with jQuery instruction $.when()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to execute several ajax requests and wait until all are done and then continue using the jQuery `$.when()` method.

For php scripts this works fine, I have created several functions like this:

```
function ajax1() {
    var settings = {
        type: "GET",
        url: "root/scripts/script.php",
    };
    return $.ajax(settings);
}
```

But how would this work if I additionally want to wait for JS functions, which is located at a different location thann the `$.when(..)` instruction?

For example a `function abc()`, located in `root/scripts/a.js`. How can I perform an AJAX call on a function located in a local JS file and add this to the `$.when()` construct? Such that:

```
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2()).done(function(a1, a2){
        //a1[0] is the return value from the php script
        //a2[0] is the return value from the function abc()
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The location of the function makes no difference, so long as it's in scope.

Comment: But how would look the syntax of an ajax call on a js function? Just changing the url of the php example above isn't sufficient. How would I specify to execute the `abc()`function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JS is executed sequentially, it should be enough to include the `abc()` function as the first line of the `$.when` body.

This executes abc() only after all the ajax calls are done:

```
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){
    $.getScript( "file_where_abc_is.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
         abc();
         //...
    });
});
```

The lines below `abc()` will not be executed until all the ajax calls are done and the `abc()` function is completed.

The previous approach would make it easy to avoid calling abc() if one of the ajax returns a specific value/error. Also you can make sure all the ajax calls are done before calling abc(). Or call different functions depending on the result of the ajax calls. I'm not sure if you require any of these.

If you don't mind or care when abc() is called you can also do it the other way around:

```
$.getScript( "file_where_abc_is.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    $.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4(), abc()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4, abcAnswer) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Yet another version, similar to the last one:

```
function ajaxABC() {
    $.getScript( "file_where_abc_is.js", function() {
         return abc();
    });
}

$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4(), ajaxABC()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4, abcAnswer) {
     // ....
}
```

PS: Have not executed the code, there may be some minor parts to fine tune.

Comment: But the `abc()` function isn't located in the file where the `$.when(..)`instruction is located. So I can't just call `abc()`.

Comment: Can't you load it? `jQuery.getScript( 'file_where_abc_is.js' )`

Comment: So you mean something like this: `$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){ jQuery.getScript( 'file_where_abc_is.js' ) ...` ?

Comment: @d4rty Yes, something like that. Check the answer. Or simply include it using the html `script` tag.

Comment: But `getScript` will be executed asynchronously. And I want to wait for all scripts until i continue. How can I than insert it into `$.when( .. )`

Comment: The `when`waits for the ajax calls to be done. Once they are, it loads the script needed and it waits for the script to load to execute its callback function, the first line of which is abc() and the rest will be executed after abc() and within the getScript callback function. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes this works. But isn't there a way to insert the function call of `abc()` inside the parameters of the `$.when(..)` instruction. Such like `$.when(ajax1FromPHP(), ajax2FromABC()).done(function(a1,a2){ /*do calculations on return values from php and js abc() function*/ });`

Comment: @d4rty Yes, you can do it the other way around, put the `$.when` inside the `getScript` callback. This way, since the abc() function definition is alredy present, you can put it just like a parameter: `ajax1(), ajax2(), abc(), ...`. Depends on whether abc() needs to be executed always (at any time) or you want to call abc() after the ajax calls or you don't want to call it in the event one of the ajax returns a specific value.

Comment: Okay this is an acceptable solution for me. But to create an ajax request like mentioned in the updated question isn't possible?

Comment: `$.getScript` is already AJaX, only specific for scripts. Instead of using `$.ajax` you use `$.getScript`, but it is essentially an Asynchronous Javascript, so it is AJaX. You could make a middle function that has the `$.getScript` and returns the result of calling abc(), so the main script would call every function the exact same way, but it is not necessary and it is basically the same. Added another version in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you're looking for:

```js
var func1Cb = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++); 
  console.log('done1'); 
  var promise = $.Deferred(); 
  promise.resolve(); 
  return promise;
}

var func2Cb = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++); 
  console.log('done2'); 
  var promise = $.Deferred(); 
  promise.resolve(); 
  return promise;
}

$.when(func1Cb(), func2Cb()).done(function(){
  console.log(123);
});
```

Comment: How would it work if `func1Cb()` is located in `script1.js`, `func2Cb()` is located in `script2.js` and the `$.when(..)` construct is located in `script3.js`?

Comment: It doesn't matter in which js file they are located as long as script3 code will execute after script1 and script2 are finished loading

Comment: But assume that I have `script1.js` with a function `func1Cb()` and a `script2.js` with a function `func1Cb()`. I can't just say for example in `script3.js`  `$.when(func1Cb(),...`. I have to specify the path to the script file. How can I do this?

Comment: you load you script using your html file with src tag, or in the worst case if you don't want to add you scripts loading to html file you can use $.getScript for example or inject src tag with relevant script file. No special syntax is needed to call functions from different js files as long as your functions run on the same scope

Comment: Could you please change your answer, assuming that  `func1Cb()` and `func2Cb()` are located in different files and also the `$.when()` instruction is located elsewhere. I didn't get it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't want to insult you, but either you're a newbie in web development and this case I suggest reading html/js/css basics or you are finding it hard to ask your question in the way I can answer you.
Anyhow, my answer remains the same no matter where the func1Cb and func2Cb are located.

Comment: @Pavel Being a newbie is not a crime.

Comment: @Marc, I never said it is, but if you aren't familiar with basics its hard to explain advanced flow, all I did is suggested to read some basics

Comment: @Pavel If you find it hard to explain things, the least you could do is not blame it on the lack of knowledge of the other.

Comment: The only one who is blaming here is you, since person who isn't familiar with basics will find it hard to work with promises which is obviously much more advanced topic then js scripts loading. I advised this person to start from more basic topics.